# repeater control. find the table cell

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, repeater

i had kept repeater control inside Update panel. The control is having 4 columns. based on the value i have to show \ hide the 3rd column. the columns were placed inside table `<tr>` and `<td>`.
 I can find the control of 3rd column and made it visible false. but the white space of the column remains. so i need to hide the `<td>` itself. But the `<td>` id is not recognized. please help me out.

```
  Dim td As TableCell
                td = CType(e.Item.FindControl("tdcommwt"), TableCell)
                td.Visible = False
```

Note: `td = nothing` (it is shown.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
   HtmlControl tc=e.Item.FindControl("tdcommwt") as HtmlControl;
```

Comment: getting  this error : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell'.

Answer (score 0):

set border-collapse: collapse for the table so that when the visibility is false for a column it collapses